# How to stop someone else using up our Google Map API quota

Tags: hacking, google-maps

Our website has been using a few google map api to display map, auto-complete addresses, geo-coding, etc.. We followed best practices from google to protect the key such as limit referrer to ourdomain.com, restrict the key to few api

Lately, our api  exceed limit all the time, even at slack period. My guess is that some hackers somehow manage to flood our api usage with simulated browser or something alike..

What can we do to protect our api in such case?

Comment: We don't know anything about your server environment, but there are likely modules to help blacklist abusive IP's. Without that information, I'd recommend examining your logs to see if there's been repetitive requests for those resources coming from the same IP's and block them via your firewall rules. Adding a CDN may also help protect against these abuses.